# how do create a geo location login system using Node.Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to create a system where user can login only if the user is in a radius of the given location.

I am using node.js, express.js, MongoDB.

Can someone please guide me what packages/Services should I use and how do I approach this problem

Comment: How will you determine the user's location?  My ISP's IP address range is registered in a city nearly 300 miles from my location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a boundary with geojson of your coverage area. To know your user location first of all get the user's current location with the device they use. store it in MongoDB. After getting the latitude or longitude of the user, use [polygon-lookup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polygon-lookup) npm package to identify the user is within your polygon radius or not.

If the user is in the location or not you can create a function like below -

```
    let geoJsonMapData =
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              90.48509359359743,
              23.823275544984423
            ],
            [
              90.33422470092773,
              24.011030495565834
            ],
            [
              90.32435417175293,
              23.77529123645138
            ],
            [
              90.50283908843996,
              23.580546882813223
            ],
            [
              90.50519943237305,
              23.592031281422017
            ],
            [
              90.47208085656167,
              23.80909744710711
            ],
            [
              90.48509359359743,
              23.823275544984423
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
const check_in_radius_or_not = (longitude, latitude) =>{
            var lookup = new PolygonLookup( geoJsonMapData );
            var poly = lookup.search( longitude, latitude );
            
            if(poly){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

If the function returns 1 they will be within the radius and able to log in, else if return 0 they are not within the given boundary and not able to log in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you guide me what should I use to get the ploygon boundaries and the current location of the user.

Comment: for the polygon to create you can use this site [link](https://geojson.io/) what radius of the area you do have draw there. and use it in your project. For the current location of the user if your user is based on mobile/ web use the GPS to track down. There are libraries and mostly used is google Maps API. or Mapbox API to use. try to read those documentation hope that will help you.